# send array ajax.request prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm stuck here to send an array to the PHP script via prototype ajax.request method.

My array is constructed javascript side: it like like this

```
attributeArray = new Array();

//This line of code is actually inside a loop 
attributeArray[id] = value;
//loop end
new Ajax.Request(reloadurl, {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: {'id[]':attributeArray},
    onComplete: function(transport) {
    $('load-map-fields').innerHTML = "";
    $('load-map-fields').innerHTML = transport.responseText;

    }
    });
```

and at the PHP script I am getting this array

```
Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => special_price [1] => tier_price ) )
```

Notice the index number for values `special_price` and `tier_price` these are `0` and `1` . These are not the actual indexes I passed, No matter whatever indexes I construct, It reindex them from `0`. This is not useful for me because I need actual index id as well as the value.

Comment: did you try just `parameters: attributeArray` ??

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ will save your time

Comment: @BrianGlaz: Yes, It works but I want to bound this array with in a parent array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use hash instead of array. Like

```
attributeArray = {}
```

Comment: Now, at the PHP script $_POST contain nothing

Comment: As i know prototype can send hashes. So just do this like parameters: attributeArray or parameters: {id: attributeArray}